Front (white) and rear (red) lights for train Lego 60336
Has anyone added more than one set of lights to the train (locomotive) from set 60336?
In the hub, there is just one port free, and I haven't found a set of 4 lights in one hub.
So I am curious if someone use some workaround, or if there is some "port replicator"?
Thank you.

You are correct that the hub only has one free port, and there is currently only the two light module to connect to Powered Up hubs:

Using official parts, you could add a second hub, or replace the included hub with one of the larger options that includes additional ports.
If you are comfortable modifying parts, it is fairly easy to splice more lights onto the the light module. There are also 3rd party splitters available. I haven't tried these, but here's one example:

